# ¿Cómo Integrar html en código javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

comparto mi código, resulta que mi botón "Guardar foto" al ejecutar el evento Onclick se muestra pero aparece desalineado quisiera ver la forma de integrar HTML para poder alinearlo al centro.

```
        // Success
function handleSuccess(stream) {
  window.stream = stream
  video.srcObject = stream
}

var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
snap.addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480)
    var image = new Image()
image.id = "pic"
image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
console.log(image.src)
var button = document.createElement('button')
button.textContent = 'Guardar Foto'
document.body.appendChild(button)

button.onclick = function() {
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref()
    ref.child(new Date() + '-' + 'base64').putString(image.src, 'data_url').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log('Image Upload')
    alert("Image Uploaded")

  })
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es agregar html sino estilo. Con `margin : auto` el elemento se centra horizontalmente en su contenedor y con `display:block` ocupa todo el espacio.

```js
var button = document.createElement('button')
button.textContent = 'Guardar Foto'


button.style.margin = 'auto'
button.style.display = 'block'


document.body.appendChild(button)
```